# How can I plot a histogram using 5 bins?

Tags: python, histogram

In my code I found a sample of 100 values for a assuming that a is a random variable that is uniformly distributed within interval [0.1,5.0]. Then I solved the equilibrium X for each a.
I tried to plot a histogram of X using 5 bins but my code doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.random.uniform(size = 100, low = 0.1, high = 5.0)
z = 0.1  

def f(X):
    return 1/(z * X**2 ) - (X**a + X + 10)

res = []
for a in a:
    res.append({'a': a, 'res': optimize.newton(f,a, tol= 1e-8)})
    

print(res)

def hist():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.hist(res, bins=5)
    plt.show()
hist()
```

In the output I can see the random value of a and res, but not the histogram.

It appears my an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```

Can you help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: you're not calling `hist()` function this might be your problem

Comment: I put it and I edited my question but now it appears me an error.

Comment: you're trying to do an histogram on res variable wich is a list of dictionarys containing 2 keys.. what histogram do you expect?

Comment: When I print res the output are the value of a and the correspondent value of X. I want an histogram with all the value of X.

Comment: ... nope `res` is a list of dicts... check it out. Maybe you want 'res' inside every dict and make an hist of this?

Comment: Now inspecting your code and playing a bit, i see that the values in 'res' inside every dict it's the same, because you are finding the zero value for the function x in every case.. so what are you trying to do with this code? probably you're not doing what you really want

Comment: yes, I've just seen that the code is wrong. What I want to do is to draw a sample of 100 values for a assuming that a is a random variable that is uniformly distributed within interval [0.1,5.0]. Then I want to solve the equilibrium X for each a by numerically finding the root of the f function. In the end I want to plot a histogram of X using 5 bins.

Comment: then you have to call `optimize.newton(f, val, tol = 1e-8)` . I strongly recomend to not use the same variable as array a and as particular value a in the for sentence. last of all you can modify your code to create a dictionary with 2 lists inside one for a and another for res. and then the current a in the first one and the current res in the seccond.

Comment: ok, thank you. I edited my code and now it should print the correct value of X. But I still don't understand how to plot the histogram. Can you show me?

Comment: I would but your `f(x)` returns a vector for every X evaluation is this right?

Comment: It is right because I want to find the equilibrium X for each value of a

Comment: so you want the value where f(x) == x ? but f(x) is a vector and x is an scalar? I think i don't understand the problem at all, or maybe you want to use diferents values of condition but you only using one `a=np.random.uniform(size = 100, low = 0.1, high = 5.0)`

Comment: I have 2 equations: one is Qs=1/(z * X**2 ) and the other is Qd= (X**a + X + 10). I need to find the equilibrium X by doing the root of f= 1/(z * X**2 ) - (X**a + X + 10). And then I want to plot the histogram of X

Comment: So X is an array? or a scalar?

Comment: It is a scalar.

Comment: newton method is defined for functions with image in `R` not `R^N`

Comment: I tried to use brentq() but it didn't work. I can show you the code, if you want.

Comment: sorry I don't see any sense in trying to make functions Qs (scalar one) and Qd (vectorial one) equals for an X value with a random vector a of potences. I think it's not posible at all...

Comment: It is possible because it is the demand and supply model, but I know it is difficult. Even if my code is not perfect it's not a problem. I just wanted to know if it possible to plot the histogram.

Comment: The histogram should be posible always you have an array to work with, taking your interest variable and calling `plt.hist(var, bins=5)` if it's not working is because you don't have an array but other thing we can move this to a chat, and if you want share some colab note or github code

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem